# How can I use JQuery's Drag and Drop on a TextBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery and want to move a textbox.As in drag it using the draggable function and also make it droppable() so as to drop few properties onto it. I am not able to make the textbox draggable neither droppable ? It only becomes possible when I surround the textbox with a Div. Why is it so? What is the correct way of implementing both the above functions with textbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input elements are note draggable by default, because it will not know if you want to drag the textbox or just put the focus on it.

It is the default [cancel](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-cancel) option for input elements, but you can override it

```
$("#yourTextBox").draggable({ cancel: null });
```

Comment: So if this is the condition can you suggest a way by which we can over ride the default and make them draggable??