# How to make html text box draggable and resizable using jQuery UI plugins?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, textbox, draggable, resizable

Using `jquery ui draggable` plugin, I've made html text box draggable in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Text1").draggable({
            containment: "parent",
            cancel: null
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Box" style="border: solid 1px black;">
        <input id="Text1" type="text" style="width: 200px; height: 20px;" value="Text1" />
    </div>

</div>
</form>
```

But, how to make it resizable using jQuery as well?

Thank you in advance.

Goran

Comment: the function you need is resize()   See this link on how to use: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575637/how-can-i-use-jquerys-drag-and-drop-on-a-textbox The answer you're looking for is there. `cancel: null`

Answer (score 5):

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/6SF2v/)** to make the HTML textbox `resizable` and `draggable` using `jquery-ui`

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container" class="ui-widget-content">
<h3 class="ui-widget-header">Containment</h3>
<span id="draggable">*  
<input type="text "id="resizable" class="ui-state-active" value="This is input box">
</span>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
     $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
containment: "#container"
});
     $( "#draggable" ).draggable({containment: "#container"});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `jQuery UI`.
**HTML FILE**
`<input type="text" id="resizable" />`
**JavaScript File**
reference all needed jQuery files in script tag i.e

`<script src="*all needed .js files*"></script>`

```
<script>
    $(function() {      
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
});
</script>
```

*by the way why u need to make textbox resizable*