# How to Drag and Drop selected items from a list box to Textbox in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm stuck trying to find a solution for my requirement.I know this is possible in windows application but no idea about web application.So Can anyone tell me how to drag and drop to a text box in asp.net web application ?

What i need in my web application is, I have a list box and i want user select single or multiple items and drag it from this list box and drop those items to a text box in Asp.net.so how can i do it in asp.net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do this in C# or ASP.NET, you'll need to use Javascript.

Comment: thanks for quick reply.Cn u plz send me any sample code for that ?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

According to this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086111/jquery-draggable-option-elements) article, it is not possible to do it with the traditional html `<select>` (ASP.NET ListBox generates a `<select>` box).

However, you can do similar functionality with `<ul><li>`, radio buttons.

See this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086111/jquery-draggable-option-elements) question for reference on to do it using `<ul><li>` items.

**ORIGINAL**

You can use a javascript library called jQuery (and more specifically to the jQueryUI library) to add this functionality to your ASP.NET pages.

Link to [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)
Link to [jQuery Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)
Link to [jQuery Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Here is another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575637/how-can-i-use-jquerys-drag-and-drop-on-a-textbox) about drag and drop with a textbox.  You will have to do some work on your own to get the exact functionality you need, but I'm sure you can find many examples online.

Comment: hi..I want selected items (text) to be dropped into a textbox.can u send me any sample code for this ?